# pdb within eshell up/down keys dont work

Tags: key-bindings, python, osx, eshell

I am running python3 in eshell.

When I use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in my code, pdb opens within eshell.

Everything works in pdb but the up/down keys don't work for running the previous command. I get `not found` as the message if I press the arrow keys. How can I make them work?

Comment: I believe the default for the arrow keys in `shell` are to navigate and not for history.  Do `M-n` and `M-p` work?  Those are the usual defaults for `comint` buffers for `comint-next-input` and `comint-previous-input`.  If those work, you can just rebind them to the arrow keys with something like `(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'comint-previous-input)`

Comment: The command "not found" message is unusual, though.  Do you experience this behavior when running things from a clean `emacs -Q`?

Comment: OP is using eshell, not shell.

Comment: As @nega pointed out its on an eshell and not shell maybe just using shell is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't so much an answer, as a clue for someone else...

When I run `emacs -Q` followed by `M-x eshell` and do:

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~ $ python3
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 13 2019, 12:50:15) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.set_trace()
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb)
```

At this point run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and hit `<up>`. This triggers a backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Not found")
  signal(error ("Not found"))
  error("Not found")
  eshell-previous-matching-input("^(Pdb) " 1)
  eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input(1)
  funcall-interactively(eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input 1)
  call-interactively(eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input nil nil)
  command-execute(eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input)
```

Ok. Fine. I didn't *do* anything in PDB, so there's no history.

```
(Pdb) ?

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    c          d        h         list      q        rv       undisplay
a      cl         debug    help      ll        quit     s        unt      
alias  clear      disable  ignore    longlist  r        source   until    
args   commands   display  interact  n         restart  step     up       
b      condition  down     j         next      return   tbreak   w        
break  cont       enable   jump      p         retval   u        whatis   
bt     continue   exit     l         pp        run      unalias  where    

Miscellaneous help topics:
==========================
exec  pdb

(Pdb) up
*** Oldest frame
(Pdb) down
*** Newest frame
(Pdb)
```

At this point I hit up and `python3` is added to the `(Pdb)` input line, a la

```
[...]
(Pdb) down
*** Newest frame
(Pdb) python3
```

and `History: 1` is displayed in the mini-buffer. Deleting "python3", and adding more pdb acceptable input, and hitting `<up>` (or `<down>`) again triggers the same backtrace.

Quitting pdb, and returning to the python3 repl, we run a command and hit `<up>`

```
(Pdb)q
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 92, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_return(frame, arg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 154, in dispatch_return
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
>>> print("foo")
foo
>>>
```

Again, a similar backtrace

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Not found")
  signal(error ("Not found"))
  error("Not found")
  eshell-previous-matching-input("^>>> " 1)
  eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input(1)
  funcall-interactively(eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input 1)
  call-interactively(eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input nil nil)
  command-execute(eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input)
```

### tl;dr

It looks like `eshell` is getting confused by the subprocess. Either it understands it's in a sub-process and doesn't know how to record history, or it has no idea it's in a sub-process and is trying to count the prompt as part of the input and again getting confused. Either way, not being an `eshell` user, I'd chalk this up as a bug (or a missing feature).

Maybe using `M-x shell` and @LoremIpsum's suggestion to remap `<up>` you'll have better luck.

Comment: Interesting analysis. Seems like a missing feature to me too.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me: setting variable `realgud-populate-common-fn-keys-function` to `nil`

Answer (score 0):

As implied by the research @nega has done, it looks like `eshell` doesn't capture the input of the `pdb` subprocess.  This can also be seen in how `eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input`, the function bound to `<up>`, behaves.  It essentially pulls from the `eshell-history-ring`.  If you look at the `eshell-list-history`, which parses the `eshell-history-ring`, it only shows the `eshell` history, not the history of the `pdb` subprocess.

[Sad horn.](https://youtu.be/9Jz1TjCphXE)

Fortunately, you have options.  There is `shell`, `term`, and `ansi-term`<sup>1</sup>.  Overall, I've found `shell` to be the best middle ground.

In `shell`, input history is accessed via `comint-previous-input` (`M-p`) and `comint-next-input` (`M-n`).  Subprocesses, in my experience, are included in this history.  You can rebind the history commands to the up/down arrows with something like

```lisp
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'comint-previous-input)
```

I would like to give you more advice on using `shell` with Python, however, without knowing your specific use-case, I'd only be guessing.   I recommend giving `shell` a try, see how it suits you, and ask specifically about anything you feel it lacks out-of-the-box.

Hopefully that gives you a path forward!

<sup>1.</sup>  Of course, since Emacs is free software, the option to implement the feature yourself is always there.

Comment: You are right. I will give shell a try and see how it goes.